# Is there a formula to find affected square by sized-brush on a grid?

Tags: math, graphics

I am not sure how to put this problem in a single sentence, sorry if the title is misleading.

I am currently developing a simple terrain editor with a circle-shaped brush size. The image below shows a few cases that represent my problem. 
[image: is]
additional info: the square size is fixed and uniform and in the current version, my concern is only to find which one is hit and which one is not (the amount of region covered is important for weighting the hit, but probably not right now)

My current solution (which is not even correct for a certain condition) is: given a hit in a position (x, y) with radius r, loop through all square from (x-radius, y-radius) to (x+radius, y+radius) and apply 2-D box to circle collision detection. But I don't think this is optimal (or even correct IMO).

Can anyone help me with this one? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since i can't add a simple comment due to bureaucracy on this website i have to type it out here.

Anyway you're in luck since i was trying to do this recently as well! The way i did it is i iterated through the vertex array and check if the current vertex falls inside the radius of the circle. But perhaps what you want is to check it against each quad center and if that center falls inside the radius then add the whole quad as it's being collided.

Of course depending on the size of your grid the performance will vary so it's good to try to iterate through as few quads as needed. Though accessing these quads from the array is something you have to figure out yourself.